# Extracting the response body from http_post_data in PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using PHP   http_post_data() call to send data to a cakephp controller.I do it like this:

```
$response=http_post_data($url, $xml_data_encoded);
```

The data arrives ok to the destination and I get a response which holds the response status.In my case the status is number 1 which means -data delivered ok.As you can see from the code below I get not only the status number (which is at the bottom of the message) but also the whole http post header.How can I strip this message off the header code so that eventually the response message holds only the status number?

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 10 Nov 2011 08:34:15 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.5-1ubuntu7.3
Set-Cookie: CAKEPHP=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx; expires=Fri, 18-Nov-2011 16:34:15 GMT;       path=/XXXXXXXXXX/xxxxxxxx
P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 19
Content-Type: text/html

1
```

Btw, I also tried this:

```
 HttpMessage::getBody(http_post_data($url, $xml_data_encoded));
```

and got no response at all.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You want only the `1` at the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$response = http_post_data($url, $data);
preg_match_all('~HTTP/1\.[01]\s(\d{3})~', $response, $codes);
```

`$codes` would store all matches. Just `print_r` the array and look for desired keys.

Comment: Look at the `http_parse_headers` function as well. It will store `'status'` key in the array, so you may either use it as it is, or preg_match to get the status code.

Comment: Sorry for deselection of your answer but it appears not to work.print_r() of the $codes returns only the first row of the response header.The problem is still unsolved

Comment: Oh, sorry. Preg_match only searches for the first match. Use `preg_match_all` to match every possible string.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a regular expression you can use http_parse_message

```
$response = http_parse_message(http_post_data($url, $data));
print $response->body;
```

Comment: or just the HttpSocket class of CakePHP